# Python For Loop giving RANDOM errors on each run, IndexError or ValueError

Tags: python, for-loop, yahoo-finance, trading, yfinance

I'm new to python. I put together this code to pull daily Options data from yfinance for multiple stock symbols for all possible expiration dates for each stock symbol (each symbol can have different expirations dates). So I created two For Loops, first loop picks the stock, second loop picks the expiration date for that selected symbol. The code looks like this

```
pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# List of tickers
tickers = ["AAPL","ABBV","ABT","ACN","ADBE","ADI","ADP","AEP","AGG","ALL","AMAT","AMD","AMGN","AMT","AMZN","APD","ARKF","ARKG","ARKK","ARKQ","ARKW","ARKX","XOP"]

# Loop to call put and call values for all expirations for all tickers in the list

put_call_combined = []
  
for X in tickers:    
    ticker = X
    DateArray = yf.Ticker(ticker).options
    for Y in DateArray:
        strikeChoice = Y
        opt = yf.Ticker(ticker).option_chain(strikeChoice)
        calls = opt.calls
        puts = opt.puts
        put_call_combined.append([calls.lastTradeDate.max().date(),ticker,strikeChoice,puts['openInterest'].sum(),puts['volume'].sum(),calls['openInterest'].sum(),calls['volume'].sum()])
        ArrayStore = None

#Final Output
df = pd.DataFrame(data=put_call_combined, columns=["dataset_day","ticker", "expiry","putOI","putVolume","callOI","callVolume"])
df
```

My problem is; on every run I'm getting random errors, when I look at the final DF, I can see the loop was broken at different symbols. Sometimes it fails due to an IndexError

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-de7016fd3a37> in <module>
      6 
      7     ticker = X
----> 8     DateArray = yf.Ticker(ticker).options
      9 
     10     for X in DateArray:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py in options(self)
    193     def options(self):
    194         if not self._expirations:
--> 195             self._download_options()
    196         return tuple(self._expirations.keys())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py in _download_options(self, date, proxy)
     59                 self._expirations[_datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(
     60                     exp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] = exp
---> 61             return r['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]
     62         return {}
     63 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

And sometime it's a ValueError;

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-0a07edf80d9a> in <module>
      9     for x in DateArray:
     10         strikeChoice = x
---> 11         opt = yf.Ticker(ticker).option_chain(strikeChoice)
     12         calls = opt.calls
     13         puts = opt.puts

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py in option_chain(self, date, proxy, tz)
     92                 self._download_options()
     93             if date not in self._expirations:
---> 94                 raise ValueError(
     95                     "Expiration `%s` cannot be found. "
     96                     "Available expiration are: [%s]" % (

ValueError: Expiration `2021-10-15` cannot be found. Available expiration are: [2021-09-17, 2022-01-21, 2023-01-20]
```

If I reduce the number of symbols, for instance 4 or 5 symbols at a time, I can get the output for all of these symbols, but when the list becomes too many, then the errors start kicking in RANDOMLY. Anyone has any idea why this might be happening? Am I pushing the limits of Yahoo Finance API?

Thanks
MT

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar issue when I try to download a large number (100 or more) of historical stock prices using yf.download. I thought I might try using a for loop with yf.Ticker to get the prices one at a time, and put a try-except block inside the for loop to deal with exceptions. Hopefully that will at least allow the for loop to complete and I'll get the rest of the data.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29786701)